# Dynamically centering a ContentView on a ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The following XAML...

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:CenterView Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

**ContentView.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleApp.CenterView">
    <ContentView.Content>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Start"
                     VerticalOptions="Start"
                     HeightRequest="100" 
                     WidthRequest="100" />
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Produces the following result...

[image]

How can this XAML be changed so the red box centers on the entire screen of the app even when it's size changes?

Comment: when centering dosn't work i just add a grid as a wrapper and center inside of it

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT No, I am trying to find a way for a nested ContentView (maybe several layers deep, doesn't matter, requirement is the same), to be perfectly centered on the overall page (not it's parent container, the overall page).

Answer (score 1):

## in MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <local:CenterView Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

## in ContentView.xaml

```
<BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" 
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         HeightRequest="200" 
         WidthRequest="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with StackLayout.

Not that its importend to define a size for `CenterView`.

To center it vertical, Use `VericalOptions="Center"`.

```
<StackLaout>
  <local:CenterView HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But that will only center vertically.  I am trying to find a solution that, no matter where the CenterView is defined in the page structure, it will show perfectly centered on the overall page frame both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: HorizontalOptions will center it horizental. but yah You should look at (absolute-layout)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout and relativelayout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout